# I'm trying to signOut with google in Flutter with Firebase and it doesn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, logout

I'm using Flutter with Firebase. When I try to logout with email and password, it works good but when I try with google it doesn't work.

Here is my code:
`

```
try {
    switch (user.providerData[0].providerId) {
    case 'password':
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      break;
    case 'google.com':
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      await googleSignIn.signOut();
      break;
}
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    showAuthException(e, context);
}
```

`

I'm trying this

`

```
try {
    switch (user.providerData[0].providerId) {
    case 'password':
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      break;
    case 'google.com':
      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      await googleSignIn.signOut();
      break;
}
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    showAuthException(e, context);
}
```

`

Comment: add your sigin code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this code :) and this will do the trick.

---

your Code:

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
await googleSignIn.signOut();
```

the problem is you have created googleSignIn variable and signOut from that variable.

you can also try to check using `googleSignIn.isSignedIn();` this will return bool value.

---

Working Code.

```
class GoogleServiceProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(); // <----

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount? get user => _user;

  Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> logInWithGmail() async {
    final googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      _user = googleUser;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future logOut() async {
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: For me, calling googleSignIn.signOut() alone doesn't suffice, must always call FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()