# How do I use googleSignIn.signOut()? (for Google OAuth in Flutter)

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

```
static final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

static Future<dynamic> signOut() async {
  try {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

I had some questions:

1. First of all, I could not find `googleSignIn.signOut()` anywhere in official google/flutter docs. I only found other people do that in YouTube, StackOverflow etc. So is this line 100% necessary, or does `_auth.signOut()` already do the job?
2. What if user isn't signed in with Google? -> Tested, no problem (I just mentioned this, in case anyone wants to comment on it.
3. Lastly, do both async `signOut()` functions need to be called in that specific order, or can I execute and await them in parallel for faster execution, like this:

---

```
static Future<dynamic> signOut() async {
  try {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await Future.wait([googleSignIn.signOut(), _auth.signOut()]);
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question:

Yes, actually `_auth.signOut()` already does the job. But, there is a problem, when you log in with Google (not the first time), it will automatically help you to use the Google account you used last time. You use `googleSignIn.signOut()` to let you choose which account to sign in with Google the next time.

To answer the third question (you answered the second question):

I don't know, but I think both can be used.

Comment: I have also found someone on stackoverflow who uses either signOut() method (not both), depending on which login-provider is currently used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787550/im-trying-to-signout-with-google-in-flutter-with-firebase-and-it-doesnt-work Would you recommend me doing that too? (so I don't call googleSignIn.signOut() even when user isn't logged in with google)

Comment: @Cedric yes I recommend